# Rsyslog custom imfile, multiline sending as separate messages on remote server

Tags: rsyslog

I am having a custom log file which i need to send to remote server with start and end tags.

My log file:

```
<exclusive-start
1
<exclusive-end
<exclusive-start
2
<exclusive-end
assdaddas
<exclusive-start
3
<exclusive-end
```

My rsyslog.conf file:

```
module(load = "imfile")
input(
   type = "imfile" 
   file = "/opt/splunk/other/rsysloginput/gc-log.log" 
   Tag = "gclog"
   addMetadata="on"
   escapelf="off"
   startmsg.regex="^<exclusive-start"
   endmsg.regex="^<exclusive-end"
   )
           
:programname, contains, "gclog" /opt/splunk/other/rsysloginput/gcfilteroutput.log
```

So in same server, my output log shows as below which is correct, each multiline message as single message:

```
Oct 11 11:43:40 lla10703 gclog <exclusive-start
1
<exclusive-end
Oct 11 11:44:40 lla10703 gclog <exclusive-start
2
<exclusive-end
assdaddas
Oct 11 11:44:40 lla10703 gclog <exclusive-start
3
<exclusive-end
```

Now the same code when forwarded to remote server as below:

```
*.*  action(type="omfwd" target="11.245.4.12" port="10514" protocol="tcp"
            action.resumeRetryCount="100"
            queue.type="linkedList" queue.size="10000")
```

Then multiline message is splitting into single message for every line.

```
Oct 11 16:05:33 lla10703 gclog <exclusive-start#015
Oct 11 16:05:33 lla10701 rsyslogd: Framing Error in received TCP message: delimiter is not SP but has ASCII value 13. [v8.24.
Oct 11 16:05:35 lla10703.amberroad.com #012<exclusive-end#015#012<
Oct 11 16:05:00 lla10703.amberroad.com
Oct 11 16:05:35 lla10703 journal: No devices in use
Oct 11 16:05:35 lla10703.amberroad.com , exit
```

**Kindly let me know how to overcome this issue?**

Comment: You probably need `escapelf="on"` in omfile if you want to use omfwd over tcp (or use the RELP protocol (omrelp imrelp)).

Comment: escapelf="on" is not working.